# Custom Post Type Next/Previous Link?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type called portfolio.  I need a previous/next link WITHOUT a plugin.  Anybody have a solution?

Example post:
http://themeforward.com/demo2/archives/portfolio/boat

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Begin wrap -->
<div class="clear">
<div id="full_container">
<div id="content2">
<div id="content">

<!-- Grab posts -->
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<!-- Post title -->
<h1>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</h1>

<!-- The post -->
<?php the_content(); ?>

<!-- Tags -->
<h3 class="tags">
    <?php the_tags('Tags ',' / ','<br />'); ?>
</h3>

<!-- End wrap -->
</div>

<!-- Next/Previous Posts -->
<div class="mp_archive2">
<div id="more_posts">
    <div class="oe">
        <?php previous_post_link('%link', '« Previous post', TRUE); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="re">
        <?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post »', TRUE); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p>No matching entries found.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Why the aversion to plugins?

Comment: Because if it is a plugin, it's not built into the theme.

Comment: @Lucas Wynne If you want it built in, copy/paste some plugin code into your themes functions.php file.

Comment: @kaiser assuming of course that you keep within the license and IP conditions, which isn't that easy if you are producing a theme for sale.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you need next/previous links for single posts, there is the built in [`next_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) function and matching [`previous_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link), both of which should probably be used within the loop.

For archives, use [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) and [`previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link).

All of these will work fine with custom post types.

Comment: They aren't working in my theme.

Comment: Okay.  Well, without seeing any of your code, it's hard to say why. Are there any PHP errors or warnings?  Do you have multiple posts inserted for the functions to fetch link for?

Comment: I have updated my question above.

Comment: Try it with the third TRUE argument and let us know.

Comment: Third true argument?

Comment: Use this `<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post »'); ?>` and `<?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next post »'); ?>`

Comment: This is working on custom post types, but what about the same taxonomy of the current post?

Comment: @jepser (Showing up late to the party here) You would need to specify the taxonomy to use as the 5th argument.  If you only pass the first 3 arguments and enable the third to keep within the same taxonomy, it will most likely fail as the default taxonomy is `category` (which your CPT probably doesn't have). See the linked codex articles in the answer.

Answer (score 21):

```
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
if($prev_post) {
   $prev_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $prev_post->post_title));
   echo "\t" . '<a rel="prev" href="' . get_permalink($prev_post->ID) . '" title="' . $prev_title. '" class=" ">&laquo; Previous post<br /><strong>&quot;'. $prev_title . '&quot;</strong></a>' . "\n";
}

$next_post = get_next_post();
if($next_post) {
   $next_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $next_post->post_title));
   echo "\t" . '<a rel="next" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '" title="' . $next_title. '" class=" ">Next post &raquo;<br /><strong>&quot;'. $next_title . '&quot;</strong></a>' . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please format your codes/answer and add explanation to it.

Comment: Anyway I can limit that to the taxonomy the CPT is in?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`get_adjacent_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_adjacent_post/) to get the previous or next post object in the loop.

You can change the third parameter to true or false to get the next or previous post object. `get_adjacent_post( false, '', true);`

With this knowledge we can use [`get_the_permalink`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) to get the URL of the posts and create your own links, without needing to strip any junk that Wordpress adds in the other methods.

This method is most useful if you want to style the hyperlinks yourself and have full control over the formatting.

```
<?php
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false);
    $next_post_url = get_the_permalink($next_post);

    $previous_post = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true);
    $previous_post_url = get_the_permalink($previous_post);
?>

<a href="<?php echo $next_post_url;?>">Next post</a>
<a href="<?php echo $previous_post_url;?>">Previous post</a>
```

Comment: Additionally, if you want to have a continuous loop of posts you can use this: https://wplancer.com/infinite-next-and-previous-post-looping-in-wordpress/